# How to auto login after Windows Update restart?

Tags: windows-7, login, windows-update, windows-server-2008-r2, reboot

After my Windows 7/Server 2008 R2 finished updating (windows update) during the night it restarts. I want it to auto login to my (admin) account after it restarts, but only auto login after a windows update.

How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 1):

I've not done this myself, but there's a couple of registry edits you can do to enable auto login. The doc linked at the link is for XP, but it will apparently work for Server 2008.

[Technet link](http://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/en/winservergen/thread/de397f14-f9a3-4765-bc16-a6586b278a62)

Comment: thnx for ur reply. 1st I wrote server 2008 R2. 2nd I need it in the case of windows update only